# Transaction not committing for JTA Container Managed Transaction in Websphere 8.5 using EclipseLink

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, eclipselink, websphere-8

I use for JTA Container Manager Transaction in WAS.

I use EclipseLink for JPA.

I put EclipseLink.jar and javax.persistence_V.jar in WAS_INSTALL/LIB

I use JPA 2.0

#### This is the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PUBLIC" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/OracleDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>ma.cmi.model.Accueil</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Rubrique</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Affilie</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Contact</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.RegionUnite</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Telephone</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Article</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Faq</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Banque</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Gab</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Ville</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.CommuniquePresse</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Lexique</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.SelectionMailing</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.FicheProspect</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Newsletter</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Partenaire</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Media</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.PointVente</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.User</class>
    <class>ma.cmi.model.Authority</class>

    <properties> 
    <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebSphere"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.validate-existence" value="true"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I use a stateless session bean with ContainerManaged transaction and inject the  EntityManager using PersistenceContext.

this is my Spring File:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/AFFILIE/**"
        access="ROLE_CMI_AFFILIE" />
    <security:form-login default-target-url="/AFFILIE/PointsVente.xhtml"
        login-page="/Connexion.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/Connexion.xhtml" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/Connexion.xhtml" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="cmiSecureDataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from Users where UPPER(username) = UPPER(?)"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, authorities ur where u.username = ur.the_username and u.username =?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="cmiSecureDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/OracleDS" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
 class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

The select statements work for me but Inserts and updates don't.

#### I got this Error :

Message d'erreur: javax.servlet.ServletException: /AFFILIE/AjoutPointVente.xhtml at line 64 and column 61 action="#{gestionWebAffilie.ajouterPointVente()}": java.lang.NullPointerException

Code d'erreur: 500

Servlet cible: Faces Servlet

Pile d'erreur:

javax.el.ELException: /AFFILIE/AjoutPointVente.xhtml at line 64 and column 61 action="#{gestionWebAffilie.ajouterPointVente()}": java.lang.NullPointerException 
     at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:95) 
     at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100) 
     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120) 
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:973) 
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:275) 
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.*process(UIViewRoot.java:1285) 
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:711) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119) 
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) 
     at ma.cmi.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:20) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
     at ma.cmi.dao.Dao.save(Dao.java:16) 
     at ma.cmi.dao.PointVenteBeanDao.save(PointVenteBeanDao.java:1) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94) 
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.proxy.EjbBeanProxyHandler.invoke(EjbBeanProxyHandler.java:204) 
     at ma.cmi.dao.PointVenteBeanDao*$$_javassist_15.save(PointVenteBeanDao_$$_javassist_15.java) 
     at ma.cmi.view.GestionWebAffilie.ajouterPointVente(GestionWebAffilie.java:167) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94) 
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:297) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:98) 
     at ma.cmi.view.GestionWebAffilie_$$_javassist_14.ajouterPointVente(GestionWebAffilie_$$_javassist_14.java) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94) 
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619) 
     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268) 
     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83) 
     ... 69 more

Exception Error Page:

Message d'erreur: javax.servlet.ServletException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
Code d'erreur: 0
Servlet cible: 
Pile d'erreur: 
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread 
     at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:321) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:124) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:95) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.conversation.ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_0.isTransient(ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_0.java) 
     at org.apache.webbeans.jsf.WebBeansPhaseListener.beforePhase(WebBeansPhaseListener.java:93) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:76) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:160) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119) 
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255) 
     at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3339) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:3867) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:89) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)

### at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

this is my Class GestionWebAffilie :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@SessionScoped

@Named

public class GestionWebAffilie implements Serializable  {


    public String ajouterPointVente() {

        // VALIDATE IF AFFILIE STILL APPROUVED
        validateAffilie();
        int compte=0;
        for(int i =0; i<nbr;i++)
            {if (pointVenteStrings[i].length() != 0)
                compte++;}
if(compte!=0)
for(int i =0; i<nbr;i++)

    if (pointVenteStrings[i].length() != 0)
    {   pointVente.setIdPv(new Long(0));
        pointVente.setEntityId(pointVenteStrings[i]);
        pointVente.setValide("N");
        pointVente.setAffilie(affilie);

        pointVenteBeanDao.save(pointVente);
        pointVente = new PointVente();
    }



        return "SuccesAddPointsVente";
    }
```

this my DAO Class :

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class AffilieBeanDao extends Dao<Affilie> {

    public Affilie getAffilieByEMail(String email) {
        try {
            TypedQuery<Affilie> query = em.createQuery(
                    "Select A from Affilie A where A.email = :email",
                    Affilie.class);
            query.setParameter("email", email);
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Affilie getAffilieByCodeValidation(String codeValidation) {
        try {

            TypedQuery<Affilie> query = em
                    .createQuery(
                            "Select A From Affilie A Where A.codeValidation = :codeValidation",
                            Affilie.class);
            query.setParameter("codeValidation", codeValidation);
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Affilie> getListAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Affilie> getListAllByLng(Langue langue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Affilie getById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is my DAO Generic class :

```
abstract class Dao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void save(T obj) {
        em.persist(obj);
    }

    public T update(T obj) {
        return em.merge(obj);
    }

    protected void delete(T obj) {
        em.remove(obj);
    }

    protected abstract List<T> getListAll();

    protected abstract List<T> getListAllByLng(Langue langue);

    protected abstract T getById(Long id);

}
```

I don't undestand why Inserts and updates don't work.

Comment: There are messages: about NullPointerException - /AjoutPointVente.xhtml at line 64 and column 61 action="#{gestionWebAffilie.ajouterPointVente()}": java.lang.NullPointerException and 'WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread'. Please check these issues, looks like gestionWebAffilie is null.

Comment: @Gas: no it is not null, I can see the values ​​of my bean in console. the problem is when em.persist is called, it returns null, and I do not know why it happens

Comment: Probably the injection doesn't work and em is null. Check it. Also you shouldn't put anything in WAS_INSTALL\lib, check this page to properly use third party JPA provider - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html?lang=en